# Phonegap Jquery mobile Application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have been developing an application with Phonegap and Jquery mobile, I have added a sound on the click event. Each time any button is pressed, it plays a sound. The problem is when i use the app on android phone. it plays its default sound first on button click or tap and then play mysound.

Is there any way to off the default sound on android using phonegap or eclipse settings?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [event.preventDefault();](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Think you should add `event.preventdefault()` to the end of your click event function. This is usually used to prevent the default action of an event.